# File not found error Google Drive API: Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-drive-api

I'm building spring boot api using Drive API to assign permission to a user (through email ID) by granting access to a folder created under shared drive

I get the error `"message" : "File not found: i6fBhgd*********",`

Details below:

**Controller:**

```
package com.test.drive.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.drive.business.DriveBoException;
import com.test.drive.business.FolderBo;
import com.test.drive.util.DriveIntegrationUtil;
import com.test.drive.vo.DriveFolderVo;

@RestController
public class FolderController {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = FolderController.class.getName();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);
    @Autowired
    private FolderBo folderBo;

    // Folder Permission
    @PostMapping("/folderpermission")
    public DriveFolderVo folderPermission(@RequestBody DriveFolderVo driverFolderVo) {
        try {
            folderBo.folderPermission(driverFolderVo.getFolderId(), driverFolderVo.getEmailId());
        } catch (DriveBoException e) {
            LOGGER.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASS_NAME, "folderPermission", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return driverFolderVo;
    }


}
```

**Class:**

```
package com.test.drive.business;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission;
import com.test.drive.util.DriveIntegrationUtil;
import com.test.drive.vo.DriveFolderVo;

@Service
public class FolderBo {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = FolderBo.class.getName();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);



    // Folder Permission
    public void folderPermission(String folderId, String emailId) throws DriveBoException {
        try {
            Drive drive = DriveIntegrationUtil.getDrive();
            // List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files.List request = drive.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, createdTime)").setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false");
            Permission permission = new Permission();
            permission.setEmailAddress(emailId);
            permission.setType("user");
            permission.setRole("reader");
            drive.permissions().create(folderId, permission).setTransferOwnership(false).execute();
            request.setIncludeTeamDriveItems(true);
            request.setSupportsTeamDrives(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASS_NAME, "folderPermission", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new DriveBoException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fileId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "File not found: i6fBhgd*********",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: i6fBhgd*********"
}
```

Comment: so ... do you have such a file, and is it stored in the right place?

Comment: Yes, I have the file and it is stored in right place

Comment: When I try in below URL, it works fine. In the request parameters I provided (fileID= i6fBhgd*********, supportsAllDrives=true, supportsTeamDrives=true). In the request body I provided {
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "test@email.com"
}           
   https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

Comment: My issue was that I had not set the supportsAllDrives field and was trying to access a shared drive.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call permissions.create the user who is currently authenticated needs to have permissions on the file themselves.

> File not found: i6fBhgd*********

Implys to me that the current user does not have access to file i6fBhgd********* without access they can not grant permissions

Do a file.get to ensure that the user has access first.

## what to do.

The problem you have right now is the person running the file the one who has authorized it does not have access.  You need the owner of the file to run the application authorize it that person can then change the permissions on the file.

You need access to private data before you can change it.

Comment: @DalmTo The user has 'Manager' role assigned for the shared drive. When I tried file.get through UI, it returned the same error.

Comment: Exactly the user doesn't have access.   just because you are manager doesn't mean you have access to everything.    Fix the users access and they will be able to access the file and then change the permissions.

Comment: @DalmTo How do I fix the access ? I only have the options (Viewer, Commenter, Contributor, Content Manager, Manager) I tried to change access from 'Manager' to 'Content Manager' and it returns same error

Comment: Have the owner of the file grant them access.  I don't think this is something you can force just because they are manager.

Comment: Do you mean through UI where the owner of the file can grant access ? It's possible through UI as the owner get notification to grant access. But is it not possible through API ?

Comment: Sure have the owner of the file run your application and authorize it and grant someone else access.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean, its not possible through API ?

Comment: It means it is possible though the API if you have the owner of the file run the application and authorize it that user can then change the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

**If you check the Drive API [error page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid):**

> The `notFound` error occurs when the user does not have read access to a file, or the file does not exist.
>
> To fix this error:
>
> 1. Inform the user they don't have read access to the file or that the file doesn't exist.
> 2. Instruct the user to ask the owner for permission to the file.

Therefore, since you mentioned that the file does in fact exist, it seems that what you are encountering is in fact an error related to file's permissions.

**Just like mentioned above, if you want to change the permissions of a file, first you must have the read access to the file itself.**

If you have a single owner of the files in the shared drive, you might benefit from creating a service account which ends up impersonating this owner. In this way, the service account acts as the owner of these files and it may be easier and more secure to create the permissions as no other permissions need to be added to the file.

#### Reference

- [Drive API Resolve Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

Comment: Thank you for the details. I tried as below                                                                    
1. Create service account (g-service account) and assigned 'Manager' role for this shared drive.                                                                                                                   2. When I do GET call to list all the folders, it works fine                                            3. When I do POST call to assign 'reader' role to my email for a folder under under this shared drive, it returns the same error

Comment: But what permissions do you have for this folder? Can you retrieve the permissions for this specific folder only?

Comment: When I do GET call to (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) to list all the permission for this specific folder, I see both service account and g-service account has 'organizer' role

Comment: What about the `view` in the response? What if you explicitly add the reader role as well?

Comment: From the response there is no ```view``` field. I only see as below ```{
    "kind": "drive#permissionList",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#permission",
            "id": "025043000234",
            "type": "user",
            "role": "organizer"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#permission",
            "id": "0283762644325",
            "type": "user",
            "role": "organizer"
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: Same error when I explicitly add the reader role. ```permission.setRole("reader");```